# Mysql update count union based on first table

Tags: mysql, sql-update, union

I would like to update a table (category) to save how many items are affected to this category (or sub-category from this parent category)

I have this:

```sql
update category as a 
set nb_items = (select count(distinct item_id) from (
        select item_id from item_category where category_id = a.id
        union all
        select item_category.item_id
        from category as sub_cat
        inner join item_category
            on item_category.category_id = sub_cat.id
        where sub_cat.parent_id = a.id
    ) as tmp
)
where category.parent_id is null
```

But it complains that `a.id` is unknown.

I will use a workaround, but I am curious to know how to do this (using a single statement, no temporary tables)

Thank you all!

Best,

**EDIT:**

Following @Akina 's advice, I got this query, which seemed to work fine!

```sql
update category as a
inner join (
    select count(distinct item_id) as total, category_id as cat
    from item_category
    group by cat
    union all
    select count(distinct item_category.item_id) as total, top_cat.id as cat
    from category as top_cat
    inner join category as sub_cat
        on sub_cat.parent_id = top_cat.id
    inner join item_category
        on item_category.category_id = sub_cat.id
    group by cat
) as tmp
on tmp.cat = a.id
set a.nb_items = tmp.total
where a.parent_id is null;
```

I'm not 100% sure it removes duplicates, but looking at the results it seems ok.

Thanks again to @Akina !

Comment: You cannot use correlated query in SET clause. Make according subquery and join it to your table in FROM clause.

Comment: Thank you @Akina ! It seems to be working fine :) :) :)
I updated my original post with a query I wrote according to your advice, and I was indeed looking at it from the wrong angle. Thank you again!